# How to catch the event of change of <select > with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

```
<select id="target">
<option value="1">item1</option>
<option value="2">item2</option>
<option value="3">item3</option>
</select>
```

Say,I want to do some processing according to selected value.

Comment: What if they click on the already selected item?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$('#target').change( function() {
   $(this).find(":selected").each(function () {
            console.log( $(this).val() );
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#target").change( function() {
    alert($("#target option:selected").val());
});
```

You may also need to consider this as well if the person does not change the option, but simply clicks on the drop down and selects the same item:

```
$("#target option").click( function() {
     alert($("#target option:selected").val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#target").change( function() {
  var selectedOption = $("#target option:selected");
  var selectedValue = selectedOption.val();  // gets the selected value
  var selectedText = selectedOption.text();  // gets the selected text
});
```

Comment: Please add details to your answer concerning how to acquire the selected value within the event handler (it's mentioned in the OP).

Comment: your initial selector appears to have some random characters ']

Comment: Also, replace `selected` by `selectedOption` or the opposite

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is okay but do not catch changes done by keypress (arrow-keys or alphanum keys).

This is a better apporach:

```
$('#target').bind("change keyup",function() {
   $(this).find(":selected").each(function () {
     // do something amazing here
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected value and text simply by:

```
$("#target").change(function() {
  var selectedValue = $(this).val(),
      selectedText = $('option:selected', this).text();
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using arrow-function, it can be :

```
$('#target').change((e) =>{
        console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
        console.log(e.currentTarget.textContent);
 });
```

Replacing `this` by `event.currentTarget` .